# SqlServerCE version 3.5 SP2 - Database file is larger than configured maximum

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

Here is some sample code of how I am creating/connecting/working with my database

```
string connection = @"Data Source='C:\test.sdf';Max Database Size=4000;"
    + "Max Buffer Size=4096;";
File.Delete(@"C:\test.sdf");
using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(connection))
{
    engine.CreateDatabase();
    engine.Compact("Data Source=; Case Sensitive=True; Max Database Size=4000;");
}

using (var dbConn = new SqlCeConnection(connection))
{
    // Create tables, indexes, etc, and insert loads of data here
    // Somewhere in the loading of data I get
    // the "Database file is larger..." exception
}
```

Here is my question. The database file size at the point of the exception is a mere 368 MB (386,879,488 bytes to be exact according to the file properties). Do I need to add the max database size string into the Compact statement?

Any other ideas on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for Max Database Size is 256 MB, so yes, you would need to add this to the connection string, if the file size grows over this.

Comment: It is in the connection string, did you mean in the compact call?

Comment: I added the Max Database Size string into the Compact method call, still same behavior. On the upside, it is still identical behavior, file size is 386,879,488 bytes.

Comment: Okay, I think I have figured it out, you are correct, I just missed that in my actual code I had a secondary method that was performing operations on the data and it was in that code that the exception came from. Turns out I was using a different connection string there in which I did not specify the Max DB Size. Testing now, but I believe that is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As had ErikEJ said, this is how the connection string have to be:

"Data Source=MyData.sdf;**Max Database Size=256**;Persist Security Info=False;"

where you can replace 256 with a needed size.